# Is there a way to block all news from a particular source in Yahoo News?

Tags: yahoo

I use Yahoo News (news aggregator) rather than accessing trusted news sources directly because I like the variety of news they provide.

To the right of each Yahoo News item is a kebab menu (three vertical dots) with an option to show less news from that news item's source.

For example, if the source of the news item was Reuters then the option would be **"Show Less from Reuters"**
 
[image: Show Less from Reuters]

The "Show Less" option decreases but doesn't completely eliminate items from a source.

Is there a way to completely eliminate news items from a particular source?

Answer (score 2):

There is no longer an option to **"Show Less from [news-source]"**

Yahoo removed the "3-dots" menu that included the option over a year ago.

There is no way to block publishers. I called Yahoo tech support and they offered no alternative but confirmed the change.